# "Enter" Key cause Server Trip each time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net (vb.net) web application form in which there are so many aspx controls.
I select some of the value of the controls.
Now when i clicked on radio button(checkboxlist,button etc),it went to the server side to execute the code.
Now at a same time when i pressed "Enter Key",all the previous selection of the aspx control got clear.
what is the solution for that.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode === 13)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: you can use update pannel

Comment: By default, enter submits the form. You could use UseSubmitBehavior="false" on your button but I'm not sure how well it works on other browser than IE

Comment: @GhanshyamLakhani i put UseSubmitBehavior="false" property of each button which cause the postback thats it.
your solution may be right also..Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, enter submits the form. Instead of doing it in javascript yourself, you could use [UseSubmitBehavior="false"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) on your button. I'm not sure how well it works on other browser than IE

Comment: your solution useful for me because i did not code anything on load event when postback occur.
so when i press "Enter" key as per your solution button click event did not called automatically,but it went to load event.what to do to prevent such calls to the server side

Comment: @Tarang unless you have something else, just using this property should prevent any postback when pressing enter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210338/enter-key-causes-the-unnecessary-post-back/30211028?noredirect=1#comment48529059_30211028

ya solution for this is here