# Enter key causes the unnecessary post-back

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, autopostback

I have a web-application form in vb.net.
When I click on a radio button, a postback is run on the server. If I press enter at the same time it causes another postback to the server. How do I prevent that second postback?

```
<td class="tdClassic" id="tdCT">
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbSingle" runat="server" Text="Singl" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="grpT" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbMultiple" runat="server" Text="Multiple" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="grpTrainer" />
</td>
```

Comment: How can you click on radio button and press enter at the same time, is that common practise ?

Comment: If you have autopostback set for the radio button, then all of this behavior is as desired. To stop the form posting back when you hit enter you'll need to use javascript

Comment: no that is not a common practice 
Accidentally i find out that thing in my web application. 
usually user not suppose to do that type of practice but for my knowledge i  want to know about this.

Comment: @Tarang: why do you care about things that most likely never will happen? Do you use event handlers or is all your logic in `Page_Load`? If you use the `RadioButton`'s `CheckedChanged` event, it should not be triggered when the user presses enter.

Comment: @matt_lethargic is there no any property in .net?
if no then how to prevent with javascript?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes i use page_load to retrieve by-default values when page call first time

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx There is an autopostback property. Why not post code then someone will be able to find the problem straight away. And please clarify the actual issue

Comment: @matt_lethargic as you say I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you can stop the endter key from submitting the form using:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode === 13)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

if not this might work:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var nav = window.Event ? true : false;
if (nav) {
window.captureEvents(Event.KEYDOWN);
window.onkeydown = NetscapeEventHandler_KeyDown;
} else {
document.onkeydown = MicrosoftEventHandler_KeyDown;
}

function NetscapeEventHandler_KeyDown(e) {
if (e.which == 13 && e.target.type != 'textarea' && e.target.type != 'submit') { 
return false; 
}
return true;
}

function MicrosoftEventHandler_KeyDown() {
if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.srcElement.type != 'textarea' && 
event.srcElement.type!= 'submit')
return false;
return true;
}
</script>
```

or if you have a button on the page then `UseSubmitBehavior` might be a better solution:

```
<asp:button id="Button1" text="Submit" onclick="SubmitBtn_Click"    usesubmitbehavior="false" runat="server"/>
```

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx

Comment: wow,Above two solution is working for me.
but i want to tell you about  usesubmitbehavior="false"
as i know about this if you assign property then it only prevent click event of that button
but me.load event will not be prevented by this.when you press enter than me.load always gets execute
m i right or wrong?please clear my view!!

Comment: Me.Load gets executed when the page is loaded or if it is Posted Back. What causes the postback can vary.

Comment: so Me.Load is the first event to be called when any postback occur.After that specific event for any control gets executed
is it right?

Comment: yes, for every postback and when the page loads the first time. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx